# (omnet++)Explaining how the SNR value is calculate in INET and imagining the noise?

Tags: omnet++, inet

As far as I know about SNR is the signal to noise ratio or the difference of noise and signal strength, so what I want is SNR value for a signal that a Mobile node will detect from an access point, hence how the noise will put or estimate to calculate the SNR?

While I explored the source codes of INET, I found `getSNR()` and `setSNR()`, but I don't know how they work in OMNeT++?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the calculation of the `SNR` happens in lower layers and is closely related to the propagation model used in your application.

This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728592/4786271

---

`getSNR()` and `setSNR()` sound like function which are used to put information into OMNeT++ packets.

I'd suggest you have a look at `Radio.h` and `Radio.cc`. The following functions might be useful:

```
/** @brief Buffer the frame and update noise levels and snr information */
virtual void handleLowerMsgStart(AirFrame *airframe);

/** @brief Unbuffer the frame and update noise levels and snr information */
virtual void handleLowerMsgEnd(AirFrame *airframe);

/** Sends a message to the upper layer */
virtual void sendUp(AirFrame *airframe);
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response,as you mentioned above, I checked the both modules and I cant get my answer, any way the new version of INET 3.0 has been changed many physical layer modules, and through my exploring I found in physical layer folder RadioMedium module that contain the SNIR that a bit deffrent with SNR...